# What is a good modern miniatures Tank combat game/system?

Tags: recommendations

Short story; I'm working on a 3-d printer, and I have a passion for tanks and games. So I thought I would make a miniatures game! a friend gave me a reality check, and now I'm checking around to see if there already is a system out there that does what I want, namely;

Modern armored vehicle warfare with miniatures. I'm hoping for something that's fairly realistic, dealing with modern vehicles and equipment and goes into some depth; perhaps accounting for things like armor thickness and shot angles? I'm not terribly interested in infantry (even if they would play a huge role in real life) but I'll take just about anything under advisement.

I'm hoping someone can point me to a good system. Or if there not one, then one that could act as a base for one...Or even chicken scratches that someone once made. I feel like I'm going to have to homebrew what I want anyways, but any sort of base to work with would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Jane's Naval Wargame." It forms a turn based structure, using the statistics of real life systems, to establish analogs for the game.

Actions are interpreted from the Jane's Fighting Ships books.

A similar system could be developed to reflect the nature of ground combat.

Comment: I read up on Janes a little. Its bit over 100 years old at this point I believe? It seems like a ok logical idea to use as a basis for writing a whole new system from scratch, but I'm hoping for something I could take a bit more from. I'm trying to avoid "from scratch"